ERROR: The function TRANWRD referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function has too many arguments
I ran a macro containing:
%let FNpath=%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(pathname(Run_Tab)),\,/)); 

but get an error message:

ERROR: The function TRANWRD referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function has too many arguments.

Could anyone help me solve the problem?

Does your path contain any commas? If so, try quoting it before passing it to tranwrd with %qsysfunc:
%let FNpath=%sysfunc(tranwrd(%qsysfunc(pathname(Run_Tab)),\,/));

Tried but still got an error message. I noticed there is another place contain tranwrd:   %let FNpath=%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysget(sas_execfilepath),,/));
How can I modify here? Thanks!

Can you post the values of pathname and sas_execfilepath?

How can I find the values? Thanks!

%put %sysfunc(pathname(run_tab)); and %put %sysget(sas_execfilepath); If that causes problems, try a data step with these functions. e.g. data want; path = pathname('run_tab'); execpath = sysget('sas_execfilepath'); run;

I got the value from the data steps. The path is blank and the execpath is "C:\Users\wzhang\OneDrive - VistaGen Therapeutics, Inc\Documents\Projects\EGNRII\programs\development\listings\aelst.sas". What should I do next to solve the problem with error message? Thank you so much for helping.

You can use a %quote() function: %sysfunc(tranwrd(%quote(%sysget(sas_execfilepath)),\,/))
